# Search for Tags in SO jobs that I said I prefer not to work with in my Developer story

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I couldn't find the question about it, if it's duplicate please let me know.

I added `C#` tag to my Developer story as a tech I prefer not to work with before.

Today I wanted to search in jobs for a friend, He is a `C#` developer. I added `C#` tag in job search options and I encountered bellow error message :

[image]

I spend some time to figure out that my "prefer not to work with" section of Developer story causing this error. I don't know if this error is reasonable here for this situation, but I think the error message should be more expressive.

**EDIT for more details :**
In this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/4380321) if I press the third edit button (image bellow) in the third textbox I can add tags to "Tech you prefer not to work with".
[image]
[image]

I added `C#` tag to this field then I went to [SO jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) and in "search jobs" tab, for tech combobox (image bellow) I entered `C#` which I previously added to ignore list in developer story. After pressing "Apply filters" button I received the mentioned error.
[image]

Comment: You don't give much context of what URL you were visiting when you received this error. Can you edit your post to give that information?

Comment: @DeanWard I edited the question with more details.